# Align 3 buttons in a signe line, each button has different borders

Tags: android, xml, button

Good afternoon,

I am doing an app who needs 3 buttons aligned under the TabLayout, like in the picture below :

[image]

I do not know what is the best way to do them, because each one has different borders.

Anyone can help me ?
Thank you !

---

I finally did it :

**buttons.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18sp">

    <Button
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31sp"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:text="ONE"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape_one" />

    <Button
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31sp"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:text="TWO"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape_two"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31sp"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:text="THREE"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape_three"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**button_shape_one.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/red"
        />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

**button_shape_two.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/red" />

            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />

            <padding android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="5dp"
                android:bottom="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**button_shape_three.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/red"
        />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Result :

[image]

**Thank you all!**

Comment: https://github.com/Kaopiz/android-segmented-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Shape drawable for all of your buttons. For eg the center button can use below drawable as background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#606060"/>
    <stroke android:color="#303030" android:width="2dp" />
</shape>
```

For the other two you need rounded edges only on left and right.For that you may follow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935055/creating-a-rectangle-shape-with-only-two-rounded-edges) post on SO.

*Note: change the colors according to your needs and you will also require a selector to be applied on each button to highlight the selection.
The left and right borders can also be removed using shape drawable.For more details please see [This post](http://%20stackoverflow.com/questions/10571026/how-to-remove-border-only-from-one-side-of-the-element)

The more easier approach will be to use [This Library.](https://github.com/Kaopiz/android-segmented-control)

Comment: Thank you ! But what about the right border of the first button and the left border of the right button ? If I do nothing it'll have double borders

Comment: You can also also remove the borders using the shape drawable.Check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Set width to "0dp" and weight to "1" for all your buttons and wrap them inside a horizontal LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

`roundedbuttons.xml` in drawable

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

<solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>    

<stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#ff000000"
    />

 <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
     android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
     android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
 </shape>
```

Edit the shape according to your preference

In your xml layout

```
LinearLayout(Horizontal)
 - Buttons with background(roundedbuttons.xml) and weight="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use one linear layout with blue border as parent of 3 textViews with background. No need to make it complicated.